# Google Managed VM error: App Engine service account has insufficient permissions for project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-managed-vm

When I edit my appengine-web.xml file to include the requisite settings to deploy my app engine app as a managed vm (via Eclipse or gcloud), and then try to upload it, I get this error:

***App Engine service account has insufficient permissions for project. Developer or owner required.***

I am logged in as the owner when I get this error. Uploading as a non-Managed VM (normal App Engine sandbox) works just fine. If anybody has any suggestions of things to try it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might have accidentally deleted the app-engine service-account from the *permissions* tab, try adding editor permissions to "*`your-app-id`*@appspot.gserviceaccount.com".

Hope It helps!

Comment: I don't have any service account with @appspot.gserviceaccount.com. Nothing has been recently deleted, and the app deploys just fine (always has and still does) if it is not a Managed VM (i.e. app engine sandbox deploys just fine). Also, how would I add "your-app-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"?? If I try to add it as a user it sends an invite only, right?

Comment: not if it's a service account, I suggest you give it a try because the same thing happened to me too and this is how I fixed it. Go to your developer's console > permissions > add member: here, you should choose service account and add the described address, please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: WOW!!! It worked! Thank you so much! I was killing myself trying to figure out what was wrong. How did you figure it out?

Comment: Well, I'm glad to hear that! I was trying out the new cloud resource management API, and through it I set my own manual permissions (IAM policy) in one of my tests projects. Since I have more than one project, I noticed all other projects (created in the usual way, using the console) have this service account, accept for this one, to which I added the permissions manually... When adding this service account, everything just seemed to work as usual :)

Comment: This solves it! I was first looking at the menu `Service accounts/Permissions` but you need to do this in the main menu `Permissions` then press `Add members`