# gcloud builds submit of Django website results in error "does not have storage.objects.get access"

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to deploy my Django website with Cloud Run, as described in [Google Cloud Platform's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run#deploy), but I get the error `Error 403: 934957811880@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., forbidden` when running the command `gcloud builds submit --config cloudmigrate.yaml --substitutions _INSTANCE_NAME=trouwfeestwebsite-db,_REGION=europe-west6`.

The full output of the command is:  (the error is at the bottom)

```
Creating temporary tarball archive of 119 file(s) totalling 23.2 MiB before compression.
Some files were not included in the source upload.

Check the gcloud log [C:\Users\Sander\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\2021.10.23\20.53.18.638301.log] t
o see which files and the contents of the
default gcloudignore file used (see `$ gcloud topic gcloudignore` to learn
more).

Uploading tarball of [.] to [gs://trouwfeestwebsite_cloudbuild/source/1635015198.74424-eca822c138ec
48878f292b9403f99e83.tgz]
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: could not resolve source: googleapi: Error 403: 934957811880@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object., forbidden
```

On the level of my storage bucket, I granted 934957811880@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com the permission Storage Object Viewer, as I see on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles that this covers `storage.objects.get` access.
I also tried by granting Storage Object Admin and Storage Admin.

I also added the "Viewer" role on IAM level (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) for 934957811880@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68303613/5433896 and https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud/issues/105, but it seems fishy to me to give the account such a broad role.

I enabled Cloud run in the Cloud Build permissons tab: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/settings/service-account?project=trouwfeestwebsite

With these changes, I still get the same error when running the gcloud builds submit command.

I don't understand what I could be doing wrong in terms of credentials/authentication (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68293734/5433896). I didn't change my google account password nor revoked permissions of that account to the Google Cloud SDK since I initialized that SDK.

Do you see what I'm missing?

The content of my `cloudmigrate.yaml` is:

```
steps:
  - id: "build image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}", "."]

  - id: "push image"
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}"]

  - id: "apply migrations"
    name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
    args:
      [
        "-i",
        "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_SERVICE_NAME}",
        "-s",
        "${PROJECT_ID}:${_REGION}:${_INSTANCE_NAME}",
        "-e",
        "SETTINGS_NAME=${_SECRET_SETTINGS_NAME}",
        "--",
        "python",
        "manage.py",
        "migrate",
      ]

  - id: "collect static"
    name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
    args:
      [
        "-i",
        "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${_SERVICE_NAME}",
        "-s",
        "${PROJECT_ID}:${_REGION}:${_INSTANCE_NAME}",
        "-e",
        "SETTINGS_NAME=${_SECRET_SETTINGS_NAME}",
        "--",
        "python",
        "manage.py",
        "collectstatic",
        "--verbosity",
        "2",
        "--no-input",
      ]

substitutions:
  _INSTANCE_NAME: trouwfeestwebsite-db
  _REGION: europe-west6
  _SERVICE_NAME: invites-service
  _SECRET_SETTINGS_NAME: django_settings

images:
  - "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${_SERVICE_NAME}"
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: The error appears to be, in part, from your `gcloud builds submit` command. Please include that. `googleapi` is curious. This should be `googleapis` but it's unclear why that's being reference by `gcloud builds submit`. Although the error says GCS, it's incorrectly|unable to reference the bucket in the error and so I think it may be a red-herring (misleading).

Comment: My command is `gcloud builds submit --config cloudmigrate.yaml --substitutions _INSTANCE_NAME=trouwfeestwebsite-db,_REGION=europe-west6`. The referenced cloudmigrate.yaml is listed in the question, what other referenced things have I missed? `gcloud --version` returns: Google Cloud SDK 361.0.0, bq 2.0.71, core 2021.10.15, gsutil 5.4. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solved my problem.

1. DazWilkin was right in saying:

   > it's incorrectly|unable to reference the bucket

   (comment upvote for that, thanks!!). In my secret (configured on Secret Manager; or alternatively you can put this in a .env file at project root folder level and making sure you don't exclude that file for deployment in a .gcloudignore file then), I now
   have set:

   `GS_BUCKET_NAME=trouwfeestwebsite_sasa-trouw-bucket` (project ID + underscore + storage bucket ID)

   instead of
   `GS_BUCKET_NAME=sasa-trouw-bucket`

   Whereas the tutorial in fact stated I had to set the first, I had set the latter since I found the underscore splitting weird, nowhere in the tutorial had I seen something similar, I thought it was an error in the tutorial.

   Adapting the `GS_BUCKET_NAME` changed the error of gcloud builds submit to:

   ```
   Creating temporary tarball archive of 412 file(s) totalling 41.6 MiB before compression.
   Uploading tarball of [.] to [gs://trouwfeestwebsite_cloudbuild/source/1635063996.982304-d33fef2af77a4744a3bb45f02da8476b.tgz]
   ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) PERMISSION_DENIED: service account "934957811880@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" has insufficient permission to execute the build on project "trouwfeestwebsite"
   ```

   That would mean that least now the bucket is found, only a permission is missing.

   Edit (a few hours later): I noticed this `GS_BUCKET_NAME=trouwfeestwebsite_sasa-trouw-bucket` (project ID + underscore + storage bucket ID) setting then caused trouble in a later stage of the deployment, when deploying the static files (last step of the cloudmigrate.yaml). This seemed to work for both (notice that the project ID is no longer in the GS_BUCKET_NAME, but in its separate environment variable):

   ```
   DATABASE_URL=postgres://myuser:mypassword@//cloudsql/mywebsite:europe-west6:mywebsite-db/mydb
   GS_PROJECT_ID=trouwfeestwebsite
   GS_BUCKET_NAME=sasa-trouw-bucket
   SECRET_KEY=my123Very456Long789Secret0Key
   ```
2. Then, it seemed that there also really was a permissions problem:

   - for the sake of completeness, afterwards, I tried adding the permissions as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55635575/5433896, but it didn't prevent the error I reported in my question.
   - This answer however helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33923292/5433896. =>
     Setting the `Editor` role on the cloudbuild service account helped the gcloud builds submit command to continue its process further without throwing the permissions error.
3. If you have the same problem: I think a few things mentioned in my question can also help you - for example I think doing this may also have been important:

   > I enabled Cloud run in the Cloud Build permissons tab:
   > https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/settings/service-account?project=trouwfeestwebsite